# Match column values of 2 different dataframe but of different length

Tags: python, pandas

[image: CHECK DATASET IMAGE]

I have TOTAL 2 dataset where dataset1 has PATIENTID column of around 40 entries and another dataset2 has Same PATIENTID of around 700 entries

I want to check if the PATIENTID of dataset1 are present in dataset2 or not.

I tried in Python Jupyter notebook, it is not working though through Python code.

```
PatientsNotTreated=unique(Datase1.PatientID)[!unique(Dataset1.PatientID) in unique(Dataset2.PatientID)]
PatientsNotTreated
```

I am getting error:

```
PatientsNotTreated=unique(Datase1.PatientID)[!unique(Dataset1.PatientID) in unique(Dataset2.PatientID)]
                                                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expect output of patientID which are not present in daTASET2

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, do you want to filter the dataset1 according to the patients that aren't in the dataset2 or just get the list of unique patients 
that are only in the dataset1?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I have asked another question with same dataset if youy guys can help would be great help thanks!

Comment: That question must be asked apart from this. Send me the link

Comment: Yes this is the link-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287536/nested-loop-to-find-proportion?noredirect=1#comment102940603_58287536

Comment: @ansev if you can check the 2nd qquestion link nd help it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to make a [boolena indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Finally use [Series.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
arr_out=Dataset1.loc[~Dataset1['PatientID'].isin(Dataset2['PatientID']),'PatientID'].unique()
```

---

```
arr_in=Dataset1.loc[Dataset1['PatientID'].isin(Dataset2['PatientID']),'PatientID'].unique()
```

---

to filter dataset1 according to the patient use:

```
Dataset1_filtered=Dataset1.loc[~Dataset1['PatientID'].isin(Dataset2['PatientID'])]
```

Comment: bro i have added answer can you also answer that question too pls thanks in advance

Comment: I already clicked on upvote but i am getting "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: I have asked another question if you can help

Comment: @halfer yes i have done it thanlks for teaching can you solve my 2nd question i sent you the link and what is the use of ' ~  ' this which you used in above code?

Comment: if you can help me in solving another questiion whcih i have posted would be great help